# How does Google Local Services Ads know what calls our call center is receiving?

Tags: google-ad-manager

When our call center gets a call from a new customer, it shows up on our Google Local Services ads web page. How does Google know who is calling us?

Answer (score 0):

Because when the company signs up with Google LSA, they get a forwarding number for their company. So the customer is calling a number provided by Google, which gets forwarded to the call intake of the company. That's how they know who is calling. (I think.)